# What is the proper use of the word ли?

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова, conjunctions

My understanding is that it means "whether" in some contexts, but can mean "if" in others. What is the difference in usage?

And what might be the difference between ли and Если, assuming that they both can mean "if?"

Answer (score 19):

*if* has two meanings. One meaning is the most common one, the one that suggests a condition. This meaning is rendered into Russian as если:

> If it rains, we'll stay home.
>
> Если пойдет дождь, мы останемся дома.

The other meaning of *if* is *whether*. This meaning is rendered into Russian as ли:

> I don't know if it will rain.
>
> Я не знаю, пойдет ли дождь.

Ли is also used to emphasize a question:

> Он придет? Will he come? Simple question
>
> Придет ли он? Will he come? More emphatic. Implies that this is a very important question or can also imply that there's certain doubt that he will come.

Ли is sometimes contracted to ль, but this usage is rare in Modern Russian.

> Все так же ль осеняют своды 
> Сей храм парнасских трех цариц? 
> Все те же ль клики юных жриц? 
> Все те же ль вьются хороводы?.. (Пушкин)

When ли is used, the natural subject-verb order is usualy inverted (see the examples above).

Comment: +1 Nice answer! I wish some grammar books were as plain as this. :D

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that the first usage of ли (as in "Придет ли он?") is also often found in compound sentences and not just questions.  This is pretty much the *whether* version of its usage.  For example:

> Я не знаю, пойдет ли дождь. (I don't know whether it will rain.)

Finally, it can be used with a *maybe* meaning:

> То ли дождь, то ли снег. (Maybe rain, maybe snow.)

Answer (score 3):

"Ли" can mean "whether" in some cases, for example:

> Whether rain or snow
>
> Дождь ли, снег ли

Which can be shortened to

> Дождь ли, снег

However, that form is more poetic than what is usually called for. The following is much more natural

> Дождь или снег

Comment: `ли` is not a contraction of `или`.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I never claimed it was.

Comment: There is something unclear / a typo in the answer (second example). I cannot edit it---I don't understand what you wanted to say.

Comment: @texnic thanks for bringing that to my attention, fixed.

Comment: You're welcome :) However I am afraid I still don't understand this example. I cannot imagine the first one to be shortened like that.

Comment: @texnic I don't suppose you've watched Служебный роман?

Comment: OK, you're right, this didn't come up in my memory :) But is it used anywhere else? I mean, should we give as an example of the proper use (original question) an example from a poem, that is hardly applicable both in writing and in speech? So, I don't say it's wrong, I just wouldn't write that ``Дождь ли, снег ли`` can be shortened like this. At least not in an FAQ-style answer.

Comment: @texnic that's why I said it is way too poetic for everyday usage.